# How to calculate the `Target budget yield performance ratio` in python

Tags: python, visualization

I have the following plot:
[image]

Instruction I got:

```
The green line represents the budget line. It starts at 73.9 and should reduce by 0.8% every year(Do not hardcode the values). As you can see the values are:
73.9 first year
73.3 second year
72.7 third year

This should happen dynamically through code
```

Link for full [query](https://cleantechenergycorp.sharepoint.com/sites/CleantechPublicLibrary/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?id=%2Fsites%2FCleantechPublicLibrary%2FShared%20Documents%2FIntern%20Selection%20Task%20-%20O%26M%20IT%2FAssignment_Task%2Epdf&parent=%2Fsites%2FCleantechPublicLibrary%2FShared%20Documents%2FIntern%20Selection%20Task%20-%20O%26M%20IT&p=true&ga=1)
How do I do it? Link to the dataset: https://cleantechenergycorp.sharepoint.com/:x:/s/CleantechPublicLibrary/ERJjBxdIl5NDqR-lRWRlEBMBVn1LQmjfssF84wicY8hFKg?e=ndhvvK

Comment: Write a loop and in every iteration subtract 0.8 from a variable representing the budget in %?

Comment: Ok. How do I plot it like in the image though?

Comment: You can use a plotting library like matplotlib.

Comment: can you give an answer using that

Comment: @KarthikBhandary , why would anyone do your internship assignment?

Comment: I just want one example so that I can do the remaining! That is why I asked!

Comment: "Example" and "solution" are very different. Also, could you do my job for one hour, as I have 7 more hours of work left? What did you try so far in terms of code for this problem?

Comment: I am not asking for a solution.

Comment: Dude, your profile is full of homework assignments. Either you are trying to get other people to do your homework, or you don't know how to ask a question.

Comment: Well I did not ask for the whole answer I just wanted to know how its done because I never did it before!

Comment: Well in that case; you just code it. Hope this helps, have a great day.

Comment: I never asked you, bro. Like what is your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code snippet that do what you wish:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 7))
fig.suptitle("Performance Ratio Evolution\nFrom 2019-07-01 to 2022-03-24", fontsize=20)
y = [73.9 * (1 - 0.008) ** i for i in range(3)]
start_date = datetime.strptime("2019-07-01", "%Y-%m-%d")
end_date = datetime.strptime("2022-03-24", "%Y-%m-%d")
dates = []
while start_date <= end_date:
    dates.append(start_date)
    start_date += timedelta(days=365)
plt.step(dates, y, label="Performance Ratio", color="green")
plt.ylim(0, 100)
date_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%b/%y')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_fmt)
plt.ylabel("Performance Ratio (%)")
plt.legend(loc="upper left")
plt.savefig("performance_ratio_evolution.png")
```

[image: Example Output]

Comment: is it iterating over the data I've given?

Comment: I have no access to the data you provided. I understand you provide the link, but it's not shared with everyone.

Comment: Its in the query link. You can check it out!

Comment: That link is not shared to me and I couldn't access it. But let's suppose you want to plot that data (I suppose it's excel/csv/or something similar), just call `pandas.read_xxx(file_path)` and then use the similar approach that I have shown to plot those data.

Comment: I have added the link to the dataset. Have a look!

Comment: @Yubo it's his homework...

Comment: I want this line to extend for 5 years. I tried putting 6 in the range() of for loop and it is giving me this error: `ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (3,) and (6,)`